# Why shouldn't I take the principal value of Log(z) in this case?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

$$\int_{1-i}^{1+i} \frac{dz}{z(z-1)}$$

The book's solution takes the values of $arg(z)$ i.e.  $\theta + 2k\pi$ in the solution but if we define a branch cut from $0$ to $2\pi$ then should'nt we take $Arg(z)$ instead?

Comment: (i) The value of the integral depends on the path; is the goal to find all values of the integral? (ii) By _branch cut from $0$ to $2\pi$_ do you mean a branch of logarithm whose imaginary part lies in $(0, 2\pi)$? (iii) Does $\operatorname{Arg} z$ mean the branch with values in $(-\pi, \pi)$?

Comment: i) Yes ii) Branch cut from the positive x-axis to the positive x-axis iii) Yes

Comment: I guess I'm a little confused.  Where does $Log$ come in?  I would try to parametrize the integral and calculate it directly.

Comment: Which path do you take from $1-i$ to $1+i$?

Comment: In complex analysis we do **not** define an integral $\int_a^b f(z)\; dz$ between two points.  What is defined instead  are path integrals $\int_\Gamma f(z)\; dz$ where $\Gamma$ is a path in the complex plane from $a$ to $b$.  When the integrand has singularities (as is the case here) the answer will depend on which path is taken.

Comment: @sharding4 Question asks to use fundamental theorem of complex calculus...

Comment: @RobertIsrael Even using the FTCC?

Comment: @CaporalFourrier I presume you mean the following: 
if $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$ on a region containing the path $\Gamma$ starting at $a$ and ending at $b$, then $\int_\Gamma f(z)\; dz = F(b) - F(a)$.
So if your $F$ is defined in terms of logarithms, you just need to make sure the branch cuts stay away from the path.